# How can I use the current ticket number while customising the trac template file?

Tags: python, trac

I'm trying to customise trac. I'd like to add a small "Useful links" section inside the "action" box when viewing tickets.

I have edited the *site.html* file in the trac templates directory as documented in [on this wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance) as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">

  <fieldset py:match="fieldset[@id='action']" py:attrs="select('@*')" once="true">
    ${select('*|text()')}
    <div>Useful links: <a href="http://dev.peopleperhour.com/trac/pph/search?q=%231234&amp;noquickjump=1&amp;changeset=on">view all ticket changesets</a></div>
  </fieldset>

</html>
```

The result is I have a handy link to the search page which displays all changesets for ticket #1234. Great... except that the ticket number (i.e. #1234) is currently hardcoded and I need it to be dynamic, i.e. use the ticket number of the current page. I'm guessing there might be a python variable I can use or I might be able to get the ticket number from the url (it is http://www.example.com/trac/myproject/ticket/1234). Anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable I needed was called `$ticket.id`

Working code in */var/www/trac/myproject/templates/site.html*:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">

  <fieldset py:match="fieldset[@id='action']" py:attrs="select('@*')" once="true">

    ${select('*|text()')}

    <div>Useful links: <a href="http://dev.peopleperhour.com:8000/projects/1/stages/1/deployments/new?task=deploy">Deploy to Staging</a>, <a href="http://dev.peo\
pleperhour.com/trac/pph/search?q=%23$ticket.id&amp;noquickjump=1&amp;changeset=on">View all changesets for this ticket</a></div>

  </fieldset>

</html>
```